# Defining any variable in __init__.py

Tags: python

There are many posts where I got to use the case of `__init__.py` and use to define global variable is one of them.
But I want to know is there any demerit in defining a local variable in `__init__.py` ?

Comment: What do you mean by "defining a **local** variable in `__init__.py`"?

Answer (score 2):

There is no technical reason which prevents using __init__.py for declaring global variables.

Nevertheless, the mean of __init__.py modules is to define the import structure of your application. From Python documentation:

> The __init__.py files are required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages; this is done to prevent directories with a common name, such as string, from unintentionally hiding valid modules that occur later on the module search path. In the simplest case, __init__.py can just be an empty file, but it can also execute initialization code for the package or set the __all__ variable, described later.

As a developer, I expect to find in a __init__.py file the import layout of the application itself. It's the last place I look for when I'm exploring the source code.

Therefore, hiding your implementation in an __init__.py is misleading. This is especially true with global variable which lifecycle is by definition hard to follow.

It's considered a bad practice because breaks the code readability which is one of Python's guidelines.

```
import this
The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters

Beautiful is better than ugly.
Explicit is better than implicit.
Simple is better than complex.
...
Readability counts.
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Using global variables has its problems in general:

- Passing variables as parameters to functions e.g. more flexible and readable than having functions access globals.
- In case of a network of connected objects, it's usually more flexible for objects to have members referring to other objects then for them to access other objects using globals.
- Having a module export classes rather than instances allows you to have multiple instances of a class rather than one.

Having said that, it's my experience that in programming there are no dogma's. A well known lemma in algorithm design is that from each resource (thing in your program) there maybe zero, one or infinitely many. If you typically can have only one instance of an object and it doesn't change identity, then exporting an instance from a module (so defining it in the modules __init__.py) is fine.

It's just that at the start of design you will sometimes assume that a certain resource is unique, but later on it turns out that you'll have multiple.

A typical application of exporting an variable rather than a type is when it's in fact a constant. A good example of this is math.pi, that doesn't tend to change very often...

Note that since in Python everything is an object, the words 'variable' and 'instance' are used interchangeably here. In addition to that, functions and classes are (usually singleton) objects in their own right in Python.